# Chaining RxJs Observables in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, reactive-programming, rxjs

I've got a TypeScript function in my Angular 2 app that returns an Observable, to push web API data back to the consumer, something like this:

```
public getApiData(): Observable {
    let readySource = Observable.from('no', 'no', 'ready');
    let dataSource = http.get('api/getData');
    // ... magic here
    return chainedObservable;
}
```

However, rather than returning the `http.get` Observable as normal, I need to chain this HTTP call to another `readySource` Observable that indicates whether the API is ready to call (it actually checks whether a background data sync job has finished).

How can I chain these two Observables together, so the HTTP call is only invoked once the `readySource` pushes a particular value, e.g. "ready"?

(Note that vanilla flatMap/selectMany doesn't quite meet the requirement here, because I need to wait until the first Observable pushes a specific value before invoking the second.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would mix the `filter` operator with the `flatMap` one. The following sample describes how to triggers the request when the user fills a specific value ('ready' here):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input [ngFormControl]="ctrl"/>
    <button (click)="onClick()">Click</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.ctrl = new Control();
    let readySource = this.ctrl.valueChanges.filter((val) => val === 'ready');
    readySource.flatMap(() => http.get('data.json')).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('test');
    });
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/yZL1wRw7GYhUkkhnL9S0?p=preview