# How to do the chain sequence in rxjs

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, angular, rxjs

I would like to to something like:

```
this._myService.doSomething().subscribe(result => {
  doSomething()
});
.then( () => dosthelse() )
.then( () => dosanotherthing() )
```

So I would like to chain .then like in promise. How would I do that in Rxjs?

```
this._myService.getLoginScreen().subscribe( result => {
      window.location.href = MyService.LOGIN_URL;
      /// I would like to wait for the site to load and alert something from       the url, when I do it here it alerts the old one
    });
   .then (alert(anotherService.partOfTheUrl())


getLoginScreen() {
  return this.http.get(myService.LOGIN_URL)
.flatMap(result => this.changeBrowserUrl())
.subscribe( result => //i want to do sth when the page is loaded//);
}

changeBrowserUrl(): Observable<any> {
return Observable.create( observer => {
window.location.href = myService.LOGIN_URL;
observer.next();
});
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining RxJs Observables in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180607/chaining-rxjs-observables-in-angular-2)

Comment: pay attention to your types!! `.subscribe` returns a `Disposable` not an `Observable`

Answer (score 84):

The equivalent of `then` for observables would be `flatMap`. You can see some examples of use here :

- [RxJS Promise Composition (passing data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701304/rxjs-promise-composition-passing-data/34701912#34701912)
- [Why we need to use flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471526/why-we-need-to-use-flatmap)
- [RxJS sequence equvalent to promise.then()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523338/could-anyone-give-me-a-sample-of-rxjs-sequence-equvalent-to-promise-then)

For your example, you could do something like :

```
this._myService.doSomething()
  .flatMap(function(x){return functionReturningObservableOrPromise(x)})
  .flatMap(...ad infinitum)
  .subscribe(...final processing)
```

Pay attention to the types of what your functions return, as to chain observables with `flatMap` you will need to return a promise or an observable.

Comment: I don't know that I would say that flatMap is the equivalent to then. flatMap actually performs an operation on the data. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

Comment: What if we don't want the result of nth observable, but instead want the original event without a transformation?

Comment: is there a way to stop next chained methods in case of previous gets into fail?

Comment: In RxJS 6.0 it became mandatory to mergeMap instead of flatMap because it is deprecated

Answer (score 15):

If `dosthelse` or `dosanotherthing` returns a raw value, the operator to use is `map`. If it's an observable, the operator is `flatMap` (or equivalent).

If you want to do something imperatively. I mean outside the asynchronous processing chain, you could leverage the `do` operator.

Assuming that `dosthelse` returns an observable and `dosanotherthing` a raw object, your code would be:

```
this._myService.doSomething()
  .do(result => {
    doSomething();
  })
  .flatMap( () => dosthelse() )
  .map( () => dosanotherthing() );
```

Notice that if you return the return of the subcribe method, it will correspond to a subscription object and not an observable. A subscription object is mainly for being able to cancel the observable and can't take part of the asynchronous processing chain.

In fact, most of the time, you subscribe at the end of the chain.

So I would refactor your code this way:

```
this._myService.getLoginScreen().subscribe( result => {
  window.location.href = MyService.LOGIN_URL;
  /// I would like to wait for the site to load and alert something from       the url, when I do it here it alerts the old one
  alert(anotherService.partOfTheUrl()
});

getLoginScreen() {
  return this.http.get(myService.LOGIN_URL)
    .flatMap(result => this.changeBrowserUrl())
    .do( result => //i want to do sth when the page is loaded//);
}

changeBrowserUrl(): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create( observer => {
    window.location.href = myService.LOGIN_URL;
    observer.next();
  });
}
```

Comment: RxJS API changed, see answer here for how to do flatMap with Angular 5+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47841977/2506594

Comment: As of RxJS v6+ use the `tap` operator inside of a `pipe` instead of `do`.

Answer (score 13):

#### Updated rxjs solution

Rxjs has changed quite a bit since this was answered.

- `flatMap` is now `mergeMap`

  - Or `switchMap`, they're mostly interchangeable but it's good to know the difference
- `.do()` is now `tap()`
- Chaining is now done inside of a `.pipe()`. All manipulation should be done inside this pipe

  - You can chain pipes if needed (Ex. one variable maps an array of Users. Another variable takes that first variable and maps it a second time)

#### Do something after the original call has been made

##### Scenario

- Make an HTTP call (Ex. Authentication check)
- When that call has finished, navigate to another page

```
this._myService.getAuthenticated()
  .pipe(
    tap(result => this._myService.navigateToHome())
  )
  .subscribe()
```

#### Chain multiple calls

##### Scenario

- Make an HTTP call (Ex. Authentication check)
- Make a 2nd call to pull more info
- Navigate after both calls have finished

```
this._myService.getAuthenticated()
  .pipe(
    // The Authentication call returns an object with the User Id
    switchMap(user => this._myService.getUserInfo(user.id))
    // After the user has been loaded, navigate
    tap(user => this._myService.navigateToHome())
  )
  .subscribe()
```

Note on the above examples: I am assuming these calls are HTTP which unsubscribe after being called once. If you use a live observable (ex. a stream of Users), make sure you either unsubscribe or use `takeUntil/first` operators.

Answer (score 1):

## Example for Clarification (April, 2022)

The top of this pipe can emit n values (this means the chain will be called everytime a new value enters into the top of the pipe). In this example, n equals 3. This is a key difference between observables and promises. Observables can emit multiple values over time, but a promise cannot.

The subsequent chained streams emit one value (hence mimicing promises).

```
// Emit three values into the top of this pipe.
const topOfPipe = of<string>('chaining', 'some', 'observables');

// If any of the chained observables emit more than 1 value
// then don't use this unless you understand what is going to happen.
const firstObservable = of(1); 
const secondObservable = of(2);
const thirdObservable = of(3);
const fourthObservable = of(4);

const addToPreviousStream = (previous) => map(current => previous + current);
const first = (one) => firstObservable.pipe(addToPreviousStream(one));
const second = (two) => secondObservable.pipe(addToPreviousStream(two));
const third = (three) => thirdObservable.pipe(addToPreviousStream(three));
const fourth = (four) => fourthObservable.pipe(addToPreviousStream(four));

// Pipeline of mergeMap operators, used for chaining steams together.
topOfPipe.pipe(
  mergeMap(first),
  mergeMap(second),
  mergeMap(third),
  mergeMap(fourth),
).subscribe(console.log);

// Output: chaining1234 some1234 observables1234
```

You could also use concatMap or switchMap. They all have subtle differences. See rxjs docs to understand.

mergeMap:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap

concatMap:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap

switchMap:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap