# rxjs flatmap missing

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-extensions-js

I try to chain multiple rx.js observables and pass the data. `Flatmap` should be the fitting operator but with an import of

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

it is not found:

```
Error TS2339: Property 'flatmap' does not exist on type 'Observable<Coordinates>'
```

Version `5.0.0-beta.6` of rx.js is used.

```
public getCurrentLocationAddress():Observable<String> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(Geolocation.getCurrentPosition())
      .map(location => location.coords)
      .flatmap(coordinates => {
        console.log(coordinates);
        return this.http.request(this.geoCodingServer + "/json?latlng=" + coordinates.latitude + "," + coordinates.longitude)
          .map((res: Response) => {
                       let data = res.json();
                       return data.results[0].formatted_address;
              });
      });
  }
```

Comment: Note: it is flatMap, not flatmap

Answer (score 113, accepted):

It turns out the answer is quite simple:

the operator is called `mergeMap` in this version of rxjs

EDIT:

Furthermore, you might have to use `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap'`.

Comment: And flatMap is an alias for it, but with uppercase M

Comment: Please update your answer to include `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';` since that did the final magic !!   thank @Chris Peacock

Answer (score 71):

In my case I needed to import the augmentation for mergeMap:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
```

As flatMap is an alias of mergeMap, importing the module above will enable you to use flatMap.

Answer (score 28):

With RxJS 5.5+, the `flatMap` operator has been renamed to `mergeMap`. Instead, you should now use the `mergeMap` operator in conjunction with `pipe`.

*You can still use flatMap using the alias `FlatMap`.*

> RxJS v5.5.2 is the default dependency version for Angular 5.

For each RxJS Operator you import, including `mergeMap`, you should now import from 'rxjs/operators' and use the pipe operator.

#### Example of using mergeMap on an Http request Observable

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
...

export class ExampleClass {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('/api/words').pipe(
      mergeMap(word => Observable.of(word.join(' '))
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

*Notice here that `flatMap` is replaced with `mergeMap` and the `pipe` operator is used to compose the operators in similar manner to what you're used to with dot-chaining.*

---

**See the rxjs documentation on lettable operators for more info**
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md

Answer (score 8):

Correct import should look like below:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
```

Importing the module `mergeMap` will enable you to use `flatMap` in your code

When you will import in your code `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';`, additional `mergeMap` import is not needed but you can expect errors during the AoT compilation.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/observable/BoundCallbackObservable.js
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

Answer (score 5):

**Quick Update - May 2019**

Using **rxjs v6.5.1**

Import as a `mergeMap` operator, eg/

```
import { Observable, from, of } from "rxjs";
import { map, filter, mergeMap } from "rxjs/operators";
```

Then use in conjunction with the new `pipe` feature, eg/

```
var requestStream = of("https://api.github.com/users");
var responseStream = requestStream.pipe(
  mergeMap(requestUrl => {
    console.log(requestUrl);
    ... // other logic
    return rp(options);  // returns promise
  })
);
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer for Angular / typescript what do you guys think?

Answer (score -2):

It worked for me!

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: That's how you include unnecessary code and make your bundle larger than it needs to be.

In most cases, at least.