# ERROR TypeError: this.route.params.flatMap is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

I just want to make the transition to id. Well, or something like that (I just do not know how to explain it). In general, when you press a button to go to a specific user, there is such an error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.route.params.flatMap is not a function
>
> at UserShowComponent.ngOnInit (user-show.component.ts:31)
>
> at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12369)
>
> at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13893)
>
> at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13836)
>
> at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14729)
>
> at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14670)
>
> at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (UserShowComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
>
> at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14655)
>
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13802)
>
> at callViewAction (core.js:14153)

How can this be remedied?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Angular2TokenService } from "angular2-token";
import { UserService} from '../../../../services/user/user.service';
import { User } from '../../../../models/user.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-show',
  templateUrl: './user-show.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-show.component.css']
})
export class UserShowComponent implements OnInit {

  id: number;
  routeId: any;

  constructor(
    private authTokenService: Angular2TokenService, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private servUser: UserService,
  ) { }

  @Input() user: User;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeId = this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
      }
    )
    let userRequest = this.route.params.flatMap((params: Params) => 
        this.servUser.getUser(+params['id']));
    userRequest.subscribe(response => this.user = response.json());
  }

}
```

Comment: are you using Angular 6 & rxjs 6?

Comment: What version of angular and rxjs are you using ?

Comment: rxjs 5.5.6 angular 5.2.0

Comment: @user9934609: If you found any answer is helpful then please used to do practice to upvote the answer because that dev has invested his/her time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `mergeMap` insted of `flatMap`

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
```

Take a look [rxjs flatmap missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481764/rxjs-flatmap-missing).