# Trying to make a Angular2 service that updates Firebase and returns an Observable

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a method on a service that works with AngularFire2 and returns an Observable. I want to update a counter (updating a counter may not be a very scalable example, but that does not really matter here). This is my attempt for the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) { }

  updateCounter(): Observable<any>  {
    let counterObserver = this.af.database.object('/variousdata/counter');
    counterObserver.take(1).subscribe(res => {
      let counter = res.$value;
      return this.af.database.object('/variousdata').update({counter: counter+1});
    });
    return counterObserver;
  }

}
```

And I am using it like this:

```
let resultObservable = this.myService.updateCounter();
resultObservable.subscribe(
  (obj) => {
    console.log('result:', JSON.stringify(obj));
  }
}
```

But I am getting only the first result (getting the counter value) printed to the console. How can I get also (or just only) the second one?

I have been somewhat inspired by the example found in [Observable type with two http.get calls in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851104/observable-type-with-two-http-get-calls-in-angular-2), but this example did not work so good for my Firebase case, so I have tried to alter it...

Comment: Well, you di a take(1), then you supposed to get one record!

Comment: I just want to get the counter-value one time... How can I take the counter-value one time and then increment it and then update it on the server (and at the same time return an Observable when it as finished updating)?

Comment: I just tested it (changing take to 2), and I still get only one result...