# RxJS Observables nested subscriptions?

Tags: rxjs, observable, subscribe

What's the way to simplify something like the following code example?
I can't find the right operator.. could anyone give a short example?

```
this.returnsObservable1(...)
  .subscribe(

    success => {

      this.returnsObservable2(...)
        .subscribe(

          success => {

            this.returnsObservable3(...)
              .subscribe(

                success => {
                   ...
                },
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `flatMap` or `switchMap` operator.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you are looking for the `flatMap` operator.

You can find more details in previous answers :

- [How to do the chain sequence in rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748241/how-to-do-the-chain-sequence-in-rxjs/37748799#37748799)
- [Why do we need to use flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471526/why-we-need-to-use-flatmap)

Your example would read as :

```
this.returnsObservable1(...)
  .flatMap(success => this.returnsObservable2(...))
  .flatMap(success => this.returnsObservable3(...))
  .subscribe(success => {(...)});
```

Comment: @Robin Dijkhof 
So a function which is returning observable is used inside flatmap, 
```.flatMap(success => this.returnsObservable2(...))```
then  `this.returnsObservable2(...)` don't i need to subscribe it ?

Comment: flatMap is now called mergeMap

Answer (score 32):

Previously answered for RxJS 5, I ended up on this page whilst using 6.

In the case you're on 6 as well (and I think you should be by now) you can use `flatmap` as an [operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) within `pipe`.

Modified the example code of @user3743222:

```
this.returnsObservable1(...)
  .pipe(
    flatMap(success => this.returnsObservable2(...)),
    flatMap(success => this.returnsObservable3(...))
  )
  .subscribe(success => {(...)});
```

Comment: Could you give an example if `returnsObservable2` would return an array of observables?

Comment: Now flatMap is known as mergeMap (renamed).

Answer (score 10):

The switchMap operator can also be useful.
Some examples which describe the usefulness of switchMap compared to nested subscriptions can be found here:

1. situation with nested subscriptions

This codepen gives a demo:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdXBvP?editors=1111

```
Rx.Observable
  .interval(5000)
  .subscribe((val) => {
    console.log("outer:", val);
    Rx.Observable
      .interval(1000)
      .subscribe((ival) => {
        console.log("inner:", val, ival); 
      });
  });
```

2. situation with switchMap

This codepen gives a demo:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLeOZW?editors=1111

```
Rx.Observable
  .interval(5000)
  .switchMap((val) => {
    console.log("outer:", val);
    return Rx.Observable.interval(1000).map((ival) => [val, ival]);
  })
  .subscribe((val) => {
    console.log("inner:", val[0], val[1]);
  });
```

Comment: Examples aren't necessarily enough, but thanks for sharing.

Comment: A general pattern I've found is to replace all "subscribes" with "switchMap" returning the next inner Observable. Then tack the most nested "subscribe" onto the end of the chain

Comment: For nested subscriptions `switchMap` is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need sequencing.
With RxJS `concat`, you can just do this:

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';
...

concat(
  this.returnsObservable1(...), 
  this.returnsObservable2(...), 
  this.returnsObservable3(...), 
  ...
)
.subscribe(success => {(...)});
```

If your subsequent observables need to know the values from the previous ones, you could use the RxJS `concatMap` operator.

```
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...

this.returnsObservable1(...)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(result1 => this.returnsObservable2(...)),
    concatMap(result2 => this.returnsObservable3(...)),
    ...
  )
  .subscribe(success => {(...)});
```

concat: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat

concatMap: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap