# angular 4 - How to rewrite nested subscription

Tags: angular

I have a nested subscription which I believe is not good practice, and even though it usually works for me, in one instance it might causing me a problem.

How could I rewrite the following so it is not nested subscription?

```
this.pagesService.postReorderPages(ids).subscribe(res => {
                    if (res === "ok") {
                        console.log(res);
                        this.pagesService.getPages().subscribe(pages => {
                            this.pagesService.pagesBS.next(pages);
                            console.log(pages);
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJs Observables nested subscriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888604/rxjs-observables-nested-subscriptions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always recommend that people do their best to keep *logic* in their stream, and *effects* inside subscriptions or `.do()` callbacks. So i think your instincts about avoiding nested subscriptions are on point.

```
this.pagesService.postReorderPages( ids )
    .filter( res => res === 'ok' ) // moved logic from your subscription to stream
    .mergeMap( () => this.pagesService.getPages() )
    .subscribe( pages => {
        this.pagesService.pagesBS( pages );
    });
```

If you find yourself trying to avoid a nested subscription, oftentimes you want to reach for one of the `*Map` operators.

In `rxjs`, there are four of these

1. `mergeMap`
2. `concatMap`
3. `switchMap`
4. `exhaustMap`

They all behave a little differently, so I can't guarantee that this will implement your feature perfectly. But they all have the same signature, and they exist to handle "messy" nested subscribes (also sometimes referred to as "higher-order" or "meta" streams, in some libraries).