# How to synchronize nested subscribes Angular 4

Tags: angular, synchronization

I'm trying to use nested subscribe in angular 4 but I have synchronisation problem.

My code format is:

```
this.service1.methode1().subscribe((data1: any[]) => {
    data1.foreach(row1 => {
        this.service2.methode2GetByID(row1.id).subscribe((data2: any[]) => {
            data2.foreach(row2 => {
                this.service3.methode3GetByID(row2.id).subscribe((data3: any[]) => {
                    ...
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

So, how can I synchronize this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888604/rxjs-observables-nested-subscriptions

Comment: use `mergeMap()` of observable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force observables to execute in sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336549/how-to-force-observables-to-execute-in-sequence)