# Fetching value from subscribed Observable with dynamic variable

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I'm learning how Observables work through Angular and Google  Firestore.

```
this.allinvoicesCollection = this.afs.collection('clients').doc(this.clientId).collection('inbox').valueChanges();
    this.allinvoicesCollection.subscribe(val => {
      this.fileUrl = val[this.currentIndex].downloadURL;
    })
```

I'm fetching the fileUrl with the above code.

I want to update the fileUrl whenever the variable "this.currentIndex" changes however the above code obviously doesn't achieve that.

I understand that this only triggers when a doc is changed in the collection. How would I make it trigger when detecting change in "this.currentIndex"? I should mention that "this.currentIndex" is not an Observable just a simple number variable changed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

make current index a [Subject](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-subjects-339428a1815b) and the you can easily detect changes.

```
currentIndex= new Subject<number>();
```

and then when ever it changes you can push new data. suppose it changes either on button `clik` or if it is an input control then may be on `keyup` can push updated index.

```
onIndexChange(id:number){
    this.currentIndex.next(id);
}
```

For the second part while you are subscribing `allinvoicesCollection` use `flatMap`.
You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888604/rxjs-observables-nested-subscriptions) answer for how to do nested subscriptions.