# RxJS: Mapping object keys to observables

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an app where questions are shown to users.
Drafts for the questions are loaded from a SharePoint list. Each draft contains a key which is used to load proper responses to the question from another SharePoint list. Here's how I currently implemented it:

```
interface QuestionDraft {
  title: string;
  responseKey: string;
}

interface Question {
  title: string;
  responses: string[];
}

const drafts: QuestionDraft[] = [];
const questions: Question[] = [];

// stub
private getDrafts(): Observable<QuestionDraft> {
    return from(drafts);
}

// stub
private getResponses(key: string): Observable<string> {
    return of(key, key, key);
}

main(): void {
    getDrafts().subscribe(
      data => {
        const res: string[] = [];
        getResponses(data.responseKey).subscribe(
          d => res.push(d),
          error => console.error(error),
          () => questions.push({
            title: data.title,
            responses: res
          })
        );
      }, error => console.error(error),
      () => console.log(questions)
    );
}
```

This solution works fine, but I think the code in `main()` looks messy. Is there an easier way to do the same thing, for example using `mergeMap` or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mergeMap` to map to a new Observable and `toArray` to collect the emitted values in an array. Use `catchError` to handle errors in your streams and map to an alternative Observable on errors.

This code will work just like your code with the emitted questions array containing all questions up until `getDrafts` throws an error and exluding questions for which `getResponses` threw an error.

```
getDrafts().pipe(
    mergeMap(draft => getResponses(draft.responseKey).pipe(
        toArray(),
        map(responses => ({ title: draft.title, responses } as Question)),
        catchError(error => { console.error(error); return EMPTY; })
    )),
    catchError(error => { console.error(error); return EMPTY; }),
    toArray()
).subscribe(qs => { console.log(qs); questions = qs; })
```

Keep in mind that the `questions` in the final array will not necessarily be in the same order as the `drafts` coming in. The order depends on how fast a `getResponses` Observable completes for a specific `draft`. (This is the same behaviour as your current code)

To ensure that the `questions` will be in the same order as the `drafts` you can use `concatMap` instead of `mergeMap`. But this might slow down the overall execution of the task as the responses for the next `draft` will only be fetched after the responses for the previous `draft` completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use `flatMap` to make it cleaner. 
[RxJs Observables nested subscriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888604/rxjs-observables-nested-subscriptions)

```
this.getDrafts()
    .flatMap(function(x){return functionReturningObservableOrPromise(x)})
    .flatMap(...ad infinitum)
    .subscribe(...final processing)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use RxJS version 6 you must use pipe() method and turned flatMap into mergeMap.

in rxjs 6, example of @emcee22 will be look:

```
this.getDrafts()
 .pipe(
   .mergeMap(function(x){return functionReturningObservableOrPromise(x)}),
   .mergeMap(...ad infinitum)
 ).subscribe(...final processing)
```