# Angular, rxjs : nested subscription fixing with flatMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm quite new to angular and rxjs... I wrote some code I would like to refactor because I've been reading that what I've done happens to be an anti-pattern: nested subscriptions of observables.

I searched every place on the internet to find a solution (I hope I didn't miss something) and understood what I've to do but can't apply to my case: using the flatMap should solve. Here's the specific code:

```
...
observable1$: Observable<any>;
observable2$: Observable<any>;
...

constructor (...) {
...
    this.observable1$ = this.someStore.pipe(select(Selector.selectMyObs1));
    this.observable2$ = this.someStore.pipe(select(Selector.selectMyObs2));
...
}

...
this.observable1$.subscribe(val1 => {
    if (val1.error === false) {
        this.observable2$.subscribe(val2 => {
            this.someArray.push(val2);
        });
    }
});
...
```

The code works in some way, but I'm not sure if I'm just lucky or what.
I'd like to know how to rewrite this code using flatMap, given the fact I have to make the 2nd subscribe only if the 1st doesn't retrieve any error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJs Observables nested subscriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888604/rxjs-observables-nested-subscriptions)

Comment: I also saw this post but it didn't help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this -

```
this.observable1$
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(val1 => {
        if(val1.error === false) {
          return this.observable2$
                     .pipe(
                       tap(val2 => {
                          this.someArray.push(val2);
                       })
                     );
        }

        return of(null);
      })
    ).subscribe();
```

It will avoid multiple subscribe. Here we are composing the observable.