# RxJS: Order of HTTP-requests

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have multiple REST-requests to do. The requests should happen in the declared order - one after the end of the other.

At the end of all of them I need to do an action.

How can I get that? I think there must be better way than cascading the requests.
But I am pretty bad in RxJS and asynchronous programming.

```
this.http.get <any> ("/a").subscribe ((resp) => { foo ();  
     this.http.get <any> ("/b").subscribe ((resp) => { bar ();
          this.http.get <any> ("/c").subscribe ((resp) => { baz (); }}}
);

// action now
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888604/rxjs-observables-nested-subscriptions - generally, nested subscribe calls in RxJS are considered an anti-pattern

Answer (score 2):

What I would use in this case is `concatMap`.

The code would look something like this

```
this.http.get <any> ("/a").pipe(
  concatMap(respA => {
    foo();
    return this.http.get <any> ("/b");
  }),
  concatMap(respB => {
    bar();
    return this.http.get <any> ("/c");
  })
).subscribe(
  respC => { 
    baz(); 
  }
);
```

`concatMap` ensures that the execution of the calls occurs in sequence.

You may find inspiration on how to use rxJs in frequent http related use cases [in this article.](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a)

Answer (score 1):

Use `forkJoin` for this

`import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';`

and use it like this

```
forkJoin([this.http.get("/a"), this.http.get("/b"), this.http.get("/c")]).subscribe(([respA, respB, respC]) => {});
```

the input for the forkJoin function has to be an array of observables.

EDIT:

after reading the fair point from @Picci I would suggest using `concat` operator. You can put side effects into the tap operator of each observable and still pass an array of observables to concat which will maintain sequential order.

```
const a$ = this.http.get("/a").pipe(tap(() => foo()));
const b$ = this.http.get("/b").pipe(tap(() => bar()));
const c$ = this.http.get("/c").pipe(tap(() => baz()));

concat([a$, b$, c$]).subscribe(([respA, respB, respC]) => {});

// if you want to handle http errors, you can do it like this

const a$ = this.http.get("/a").pipe(
  tap(() => foo()),
  catchError((err) => {
    handleErr(err);
    return of(EMPTY);
  })
);
```

Comment: `forkJoin` executes all call in parallel and does not guarantee the sequence. `concatMap` is the operator I would suggest.

Comment: This stops when a request has a problem (e.g. HTTP 404). How can I make it continue?

Comment: I extended the answer with an example