# BehaviorSubject In Angular making schedule (or timer) between data

Tags: angular, rxjs

Iam trying to make a schedule update for my page

like  "subscribe" and "unsubscribe" repeatedly with

to make page update after 10 muntes or so  and in the same time not makeing a headinc on the DataBase

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MaintenanceServicesService } from './MaintinanceService/maintenance-services.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-maintenance',
  templateUrl: './maintenance.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maintenance.component.scss']
})
export class MaintenanceComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  pageCards: any[] = []
  subscripe?: Subscription


  constructor(private _MaintenanceServicesService: MaintenanceServicesService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscripe = this._MaintenanceServicesService.pageCards.subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.GetPageCards()
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.subscripe) {
      this.subscripe.unsubscribe()
    }
  }

  GetPageCards() {
    this._MaintenanceServicesService.GetServicesPageCards()
    this.pageCards = this._MaintenanceServicesService.pageCards.getValue()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title is misleading. BehaviorSubject will emit values whenever your data appears.

You don't need to subscribe/unsubscribe from data every time interval, that's the whole goal of observables - you react on data whenever it appears.

In [the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jdcnjs) you can find how there is timer that creates observable, that has some `initialDelay` (you can set it to 0) and after that delay it uses `interval` value to define the time between emitted events.
So now you have a stream, that emits something every `interval` value, and here you want to do something - so you're fetching the data from your service and return it.

Another thing - don't need to subscribe/unsubscribe, just assign the result to `data$` variable (it's observable) and in the template you can use the  `| async` pipe, so it will handle subscription/unsubscription automatically.

Comment: Ok will try to make the same thing in my project thanks for the example

Comment: pageCards: any[] = []
  subscripe?: Subscription


  constructor(private _MaintenanceServicesService: MaintenanceServicesService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscripe = timer(0, 5000).subscribe(() => {
      this._MaintenanceServicesService.pageCards.pipe(take(1)).subscribe({
          next: () => {
            this.GetPageCards()
          }
        });
    })
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
pageCards: any[] = []
  subscripe?: Subscription


  constructor(private _MaintenanceServicesService: MaintenanceServicesService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscripe = timer(0, 5000).subscribe(() => {
      this._MaintenanceServicesService.pageCards.pipe(take(1)).subscribe({
          next: () => {
            this.GetPageCards()
          }
        });
    })
  }
```

this i how i made it thank you @akkonrad

Comment: you should avoid subscription inside another subscription [link 1](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/angular/rxjs-antipattern-1-nested-subs/) [link 2](https://brianflove.com/2017-11-01/ngrx-anti-patterns/) [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888604/rxjs-observables-nested-subscriptions)